# How to extend the CodeIgniter Database Utility Class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-2

**Problem**:

When I updated my CodeIgniter 2.2.0 application to use the `mysqli` database drivers, it broke CodeIgniter's [backup function of the Database Utility Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#backup).  Where I used to successfully get a database backup, I'm now getting an error...

> Unsupported feature of the database platform you are using.

The error simply means that the CodeIgniter backup function from the Database Utility Class does not support `mysqli`.  As per the online docs, only MySQL is supported.

However, I prefer not to use the deprecated `mysql` database driver.

---

**Possible Workaround (not allowed)**:

I thought I could solve this by simply extending CodeIgniter's Database Utility class.  However, [CodeIgniter does not allow this as per documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)...

> Note: The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes.

---

**Another Workaround (fatal error)**:

*EDIT: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27132530/594235) and [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27126774/594235) are based on this workaround.*

This GitHub page describes a method for extending the Database Class by creating a `MY_Loader` class to extend the core.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

However, when I attempted this solution, I got this fatal error...

> Filename: core/MY_Loader.php, Line Number: 49
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::where() in /home/account/codeigniter/system/libraries/Session.php on line 217

Line 49 is:  `$db =& new $my_driver(get_object_vars($db));`

I am using the `MY_Loader` exactly as described at the link above, and `MY_DB_mysqli_utility` looks like this...

```
<?php class MY_DB_mysqli_utility extends CI_DB_mysqli_utility {

    function __construct($params){
        parent::__construct($params);
        log_message('debug', 'Extended DB driver class instantiated!');
    }

    function _backup($params = array())
    {
        // the working backup function is here
        .....
    }

}
```

(*I'm not entirely sure if this GitHub workaround is failing because it's out of date, I overlooked something, or if it's because I'm trying to use it on `CI_DB_mysqli_utility` instead of `CI_DB_mysqli_driver`.*)

***EDIT**: this workaround was failing because it was meant only for extending the `_driver` and not the `_utility`... two completely different functions.*

---

**A Working Solution (not ideal)**:

The only working solution I've found has been to edit the CodeIgniter System files.  For obvious reasons, I'd prefer not to do this.

The "broken" backup function located at `system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_utility.php` is as follows...

```
function _backup($params = array())
{
    // Currently unsupported
    return $this->db->display_error('db_unsuported_feature');
}
```

There is an Ellis Lab thread that shows a function that works...

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/194645/

I got it working by editing the core system file with the new `_backup` function.

```
function _backup($params = array())
{
    // the working backup function is here
    .....
}
```

---

**So what else can/should I do here?**

CodeIgniter's backup function is not supported by the `mysqli` driver, and I'm not allowed to extend the CodeIgniter Database Utility, leaving me with no alternative but to edit the core system files.  I seem to be stuck and I'm coming here to see if I missed anything or if there's anything else I can do instead of editing the core system files.

---

**EDIT**: Note that the Database Utility Class in **CodeIgniter v3** fully supports `mysqli`.

Comment: If `mysqldump` is available on your system, I would consider issuing a system call to it if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involving a custom loader ([Extending Database Drivers](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers)) is relevant to just that: extending database drivers. You can't just replace a `*_driver` class with an `*_utility` class.

```
$my_driver_file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$my_driver.EXT; // *driver* required!!
```

Instead, I would override the [`CI_Loader::dbutil()` method](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L369-371). Something like this should work:

```
public function dbutil()
{
    /* snip for brevity */
    $class = config_item('subclass_prefix').'DB_'.$db->dbdriver.'_utility';
    $filename = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$class.EXT;
    require_once($filename);
    /* snip for brevity */
 }
```

*Disclaimer: not tested :)*

Comment: Yes, I should have looked at that solution more closely.  Thanks for pointing it out and I'm going to try this next.

Comment: Thank-you!  It works. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [accepted solution by @RandomSeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27126774/594235)...

I took the `dbutil()` function from CodeIgniter's `Loader` class and copied it exactly into my custom `MY_Loader` extension.

Then where it would load the default utility file from whichever driver, I simply redirected it to check for the existence of my custom database utility file located in my `application/libraries` directory.  If the file exists, use it, otherwise use the default file.

**`MY_Loader.php`**

```
<?php class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function dbutil()
    {

        if (! class_exists('CI_DB'))
        {
            $this->database();
        }

        $CI =& get_instance();

        // for backwards compatibility, load dbforge so we can extend dbutils off it
        // this use is deprecated and strongly discouraged
        $CI->load->dbforge();

        require_once(BASEPATH . 'database/DB_utility.php');

        // START custom >>

        // path of default db utility file
        $default_utility = BASEPATH . 'database/drivers/' . $CI->db->dbdriver . '/' . $CI->db->dbdriver . '_utility.php';

        // path of my custom db utility file
        $my_utility = APPPATH . 'libraries/MY_DB_' . $CI->db->dbdriver . '_utility.php';

        // set custom db utility file if it exists
        if (file_exists($my_utility))
        {
            $utility = $my_utility;
            $extend = 'MY_DB_';
        }
        else
        {
            $utility = $default_utility;
            $extend = 'CI_DB_';
        }

        // load db utility file
        require_once($utility);

        // set the class
        $class = $extend . $CI->db->dbdriver . '_utility';

        // << END custom

        $CI->dbutil = new $class();

    }

}
```

**`application/libraries/MY_DB_mysqli_utility.php`**

```
<?php
    class MY_DB_mysqli_utility extends CI_DB_utility {

    // everything in here is same as default mysqli_utility
    ....

    // EXCEPT the _backup() function is my own

    function _backup($params = array())
    {
        //  my custom backup code
        ....
```

I'm very happy with this solution as it leaves my CodeIgniter core files completely untouched.  If I move or forget to use my custom utility file, it silently falls back to the default driver's utility file.

---

**EDIT**:  Note that the Database Utility Class in **CodeIgniter v3** fully supports `mysqli` negating any need for this workaround.

Comment: Are you sure of `$class = 'CI_DB_' . $CI->db->dbdriver . '_utility';` ? It looks like you are instanciating the default class.

Comment: @RandomSeed, yep, I'm sure... because there is no `MY_DB_` class... this ***is*** the default `CI_DB_` class albeit customized here in MY_Loader.  This is the exact same `dbutil()` function line by line except for the part where I inject my own utility file.  Any other change breaks it.

Comment: The only place I use `MY_DB_` is on the name of my custom utility file.  Internally, it's identical to the default counterpart except for the backup code.

Comment: I see. I got confused because in your initial attempt, you defined a `class MY_DB_mysqli_utility extends CI_DB_mysqli_utility`.

Comment: The conditional `require()` is smart. To push it further, I would really derive a class from the default utility class, with a custom name, and build `$class` under the same condition as `require()`. In case of error, you would immediately know which version was loaded.

Comment: @RandomSeed, I agree.  See my edited answer.  Much improved as it now uses `MY_DB_` custom class.

Answer (score 2):

> The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes.

These classes are not even `final`, so I would just ignore this notice and derive my own driver (as per [`DB.php`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/database/DB.php#L140-143) lines 140-143):

- create a new folder in `system/database/drivers/`, e.g. `mysupersqli/`
- create a set of files `mysupersqli_[driver|forge|result|utility].php`
- in each above file, declare a class `CI_DB_mysupersqli_[driver|forge|result|utility]` that extends its `CI_DB_mysqli_*` counterpart (`CI_DB_mysupersqli_driver::$dbdriver` [should be overriden](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/database/DB_driver.php#L428), override the rest to your liking)
- alternatively, a brutal copy/paste/search&replace of the files from `system/database/drivers/mysqli` might be quicker (it would also make your custom driver independant from the the built-in mysqli driver, which may or may not be a good thing)
- now you should be able to modify `config/database.php` to your new driver

*Disclaimer: not tested :)*

Comment: This is interesting.  I'd rather not store any customizations anywhere within `system`, however your suggestion is still far better than modifying the core files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since making a db backup with php is somehow limited due to memory and script timeout.
How about creating a cronjob doing backups with mysqldump?

However if this is not an option maybe [this](http://www.plux.co.uk/backing-up-a-mysql-database-with-php-using-mysqli/) helps

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not with PHP, timeouts, or memory, and I already have a working `mysqli` backup function.  The question is how can I extend/fix the CodeIgniter drivers without editing the CodeIgniter core files?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is really needed to accomplish the goal. Maybe that is fixed in CI v3?

Comment: CodeIgniter v3 has not been officially released, and even so, there are far too many things that may need to be checked and changed.  In other words, it's not simply a matter of uploading a new system file set.